# Function that maps the "pureness" of a rational number?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, rational-numbers

By *pureness* I mean a number that shows how much the numerator and denominator are small.

E.g. $\frac{1}{1}$ is purest, $\frac{1}{2}$ is less pure (but the same as $\frac{2}{1}$), $\frac{2}{3}$ is less pure than the previous examples, $\frac{53}{41}$ is worse, .... $\pi$ isn't pure at all (as well as e...).

Comment: Nice question! $\;$

Answer (score 22):

You can take,
$$\frac{a}{b}\mapsto \frac{a+b}{\gcd(a,b)},$$
Note that this is independent of the choice of representative since $\gcd(na,nb)=n\gcd(a,b)$ for non-negative integers $n$.

For your examples,
$$\frac{1}{1}\mapsto 2,\quad \frac{1}{2}\mapsto 3,\quad\frac{2}{3}\mapsto 5,\quad\frac{53}{41}\mapsto 94.$$

Another possibility is
$$\frac{a}{b}\mapsto \frac{ab}{(\gcd(a,b))^2},$$
which yields
$$\frac{1}{1}\mapsto 1,\quad\frac{1}{2}\mapsto 2,\quad\frac{2}{3}\mapsto 6,\quad\frac{53}{41}\mapsto 2173.$$

Both these "pureness" functions have the property that $a/b$ is as pure as $b/a$, as we would expect.

The following table shows how the first choice partitions the positive rationals into "pureness classes". Each row corresponds to rationals of the same pureness.

$$
\begin{align}
& \frac{1}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{2}\quad\frac{2}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{3}\quad\frac{3}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{4}\quad\frac{2}{3}\quad\frac{3}{2}\quad\frac{4}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{5}\quad\frac{5}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{6}\quad\frac{2}{5}\quad\frac{3}{4}\quad\frac{4}{3}\quad\frac{2}{5}\quad\frac{6}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{7}\quad\frac{3}{5}\quad\frac{5}{3}\quad\frac{7}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{8}\quad\frac{2}{7}\quad\frac{4}{5}\quad\frac{5}{4}\quad\frac{7}{2}\quad\frac{8}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{9}\quad\frac{3}{7}\quad\frac{7}{3}\quad\frac{9}{1} \\
& \frac{1}{10}\quad\frac{2}{9}\quad\frac{3}{8}\quad\frac{4}{7}\quad\frac{5}{6}\quad\frac{6}{5}\quad\frac{7}{4}\quad\frac{8}{3}\quad\frac{9}{2}\quad\frac{10}{1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: You'd map the irrationals to $\infty$, right?

Comment: Put another way, your "another possibility" is just the ratio of the LCM to the GCD.

Comment: Why would you expect $2/1$ to be "as pure" as $1/2$? Shouldn't integers be purer?

Answer (score 11):

I have often used the sum of the terms in the [Continued Fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction). This is

1. finite for rational numbers
2. the same for $x$ and $\frac1x$
3. for $0\lt x\lt 1$, the same for $x$ and $1-x$

   ---

$$
1=(1)\to1
$$
$$
\frac12=(0,2)\to2\quad\text{and}\quad2=(2)\to2
$$
$$
\frac23=(0,1,2)\to3
$$
$$
\frac{53}{41}=(1,3,2,2,2)\to10
$$
etc.

Comment: curious, used when/how?

Comment: @djechlin: Comparing simplicity of rational expressions. If there were a quantitative use for this, there would probably be a numerical way to judge which function was better. So far this seems to be purely recreational. The simpler a rational number is, the nicer a ratio of frequencies seems to sound together.

Answer (score 10):

The order of the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) where the (fractional part) of the rational number first occurs is a measure that should be of interest to you. As you will see from the link, the Farey sequences have many fascinating properties.

Comment: Link-only answers are troublesome. Please elucidate the crux of your reference in your answer.

Comment: I disagree. The wikipedia link in question will be a very stable one. If you are looking for this kind of thing with a bot, then there's a bug in your bot (see abcdef's answer).

Comment: thanks, I've downvotwd that as well. And it's not just about link stability. Sending users on a tab chase is an annoying chore. How hard is it to add a sentence or two summarizing what will be found?

Comment: Keep at it! You haven't finished yet.

Comment: As is mentioned in [How do I write a good answer?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer):

**Provide context for links**

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Actually I found very interesting this link. It's an open door on a kind of recreational maths that, as an engineer, I didn't know at all. Thank you!

Comment: @robjohn: I don't agree with that advice as a universal principle when the link is to a stable resource like Wikipedia and when the title chosen for the link (in this case "Farey sequence") is the name of a well-known mathematical concept. The question here is (implicitly) asking for hints or references and I've provided a reference. Quoting the most "relevant part of an important link" is an impossible ask here given how rich the theory of Farey sequences is and the soft nature of the question.

Answer (score 4):

A natural pureness measure is the level of the [Stern-Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) at which the fraction occurs. Since each run of consecutive left or right steps in the tree corresponds to a continued fraction term equal to the length of the run, the pureness may be defined as the sum of the continued fraction terms.

Comment: Which is the same as @robjohn's answer, by the way.

Comment: @Anton True, but I wanted to explicitly mention the connection to the S-B tree

Comment: (+1) Nice reference to the Stern-Brocot tree. I often forget to mention that when talking about the relation to Continued Fractions.

Answer (score 4):

In the same spirit as Rob Arthan's answer, you could use the first time a rational number appears in the [Calfin-Wilf sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin%E2%80%93Wilf_tree).

Define a sequence $a_n$ with $a_0 = 0$, $a_1 = 1$ obeying the recurrences $a_{2n} = a_n$ and $a_{2n + 1} = a_n + a_{n+1}$.  We get

$$0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 5, \ldots$$

The Calfin-Wilf sequence is $c_n = a_n / a_{n+1}$:

$$\frac{0}{1},\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{1}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{3}{2}, \ldots$$

Every positive rational number appears *exactly once* in this sequence.  Thus with this measure of "purity", you can always tell which of two rational numbers is "purer".

Answer (score 3):

How about $f(\frac{p}{q})=pq$ for rational numbers and $f(x)=0$ when it's irrational?

Comment: Something well-defined on different representatives of the rational number would be preferable.

Comment: @PatrickStevens:  That would be good to mention explicitly, but they can't really be faulted here given that for lots of people it goes without saying that $(p, q) = 1$.

Comment: Intuitively, wouldn't you want $f(\pi)$ to be closer to $f(99999/76543)$ than to $f(1)$?

Comment: Yeah, it's intuitive to regard irrationals as having infinite denominator (since the divisions have to be so fine), and I think Euler or someone called them such; maybe that's a case for taking $f( \pi ) := \infty$

Answer (score 3):

I've read that Euler ranked the harmoniousness of musical intervals, and thus the simplicity of rational numbers, in a way consistent with this function:

- $f(p) = p-1$, if $p$ is prime
- $f(ab) = f(a)+f(b)$
- $f(a:b:c:\dots) = f(\mathrm{lcm}(a,b,c,\dots))$

assuming, of course, that the argument is expressed in lowest terms.

**Much later:** I should mention that I read this in *On the Sensations of Tone* by Hermann Helmholtz; in Alexander Ellis's translation of the second edition (1885, reprinted by Dover in 1954), it's the last paragraph on page 230.

**2023 Sep 23:** Today I learn that this function (plus 1, more precisely) has a name: *gradus suavitatis* ‘degree of sweetness’.

Comment: Very interesting, because my mental trip started from musical harmony... thank you!

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/136572/number-theory-underlying-eulers-theory-of-music

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can get inspiration from the [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function).

Answer (score 2):

$f(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{1}{|a|+|b|}$

For the following conditions on $x$, $f(x)$ is either zero or not defined:

- $x$ irrational
- $x=0$

Higher output values implies high purity.